# Is it correct to use $\vec F=m\vec a\cos\theta$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, coordinate-systems, vectors

[image]

Suppose a force $\vec F$ is applied on an object of mass $m$, which experiences an acceleration $\vec a$. The angle between $\vec F$ and $\vec a$ is $\theta$.

To find the component of $\vec a$ along the direction of $\vec F$, will it be correct to use $\vec F=m\vec a\cos\theta$? If yes, shouldn't $\vec F=m\vec a\cos\theta$ be the general relation between $\vec F$ and $\vec a$ instead of $\vec F=m \vec a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec F$ is the only force acting on the object then $\vec a$ must be parallel to $\vec F$, so $\theta =0$, $\cos \theta=1$, and $\vec F=m\vec a$.

On the other hand, if $\theta$ is not zero then there must be one or more other forces acting on the object so that the net force $\vec F_{net}$ is parallel to $\vec a$, and $\vec F_{net}=m \vec a$. In this case we cannot write down any relationship between $\vec F$ and $\vec a$ unless we know something about the other forces.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer! Could you please look into another question of mine-https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649178/260477

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the magnitude, the value, of the force in a particular direction. So skip the vector arrow symbols.

You are completely right that $ma\cos(\theta)$ will give you the correct horisontal component you are looking for. In this particular case, the original force is already pointing in the direction of this component, though, so $\cos(\theta)=1$. It is thus not necessary to include this term. Just calculate $ma$ and you have the force magnitude you want.

In fact, how did you draw the right-angled triangle? Typically we would draw it so that the force points along with the hypotenuse. In your case, this would turn out to be *no* triangle since the vertical leg is zero and the horisontal leg equals the force itself.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law states that the direction of acceleration is also the same as the direction of the net force. The term $macos(\theta)$ is therefore not to be considered the direction of acceleration due to the force $F$. So $a$ is the correct acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct. $\vec a$ is not directed horizontally, the prefactor $\cos\theta$ doesn't change this fact as it only can change the magnitude, not the direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can think this way: for any $\vec{a}$ you can decompose it
$$\vec{a}= a_1\vec{e_1} + a_2\vec{e_2} + a_3\vec{e_3}$$
When you writes $\vec{F}=m \vec{a}$, you're actually saying that
$$ F_i\; \vec{e_i}=ma^i\; \vec{e_i}$$
Basically you need to know what direction matters for you problem and then project $\vec{a}$ in this direction. Thats why $\cos(\theta)$ appear in your problem (but not in the general formulation).